# Сопроводительное письмо

Tags: грамотная-речь, выбор-слов

Как правильно писать: документы направлены с сопроводительным письмом или документы направлены сопроводительным письмом?

Answer (score 2):

Документы отправляют **с сопроводительным письмом** (с чем?), оно прикладывается к документам.

Но лучше сказать так: **К документам приложено сопроводительное письмо.**

Примечание. Творительный беспредложный используется в другой конструкции: Документы отправлены (как?) почтой.

О сопроводительном письме: [https://u-bags.ru/сопроводительное-письмо-к-документа/](https://u-bags.ru/%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BC%D0%BE-%D0%BA-%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0/)

Answer (score 1):

> Документы направлены сопроводительным письмом.

Тут смешались мухи с котлетами, а точнее вид почтового отправления с видом документа. Документы можно отправить письмом, то есть по почте (здесь письмо – вид почтового отправления). А сопроводительное письмо – вид документа.